# Eclipse loading a wrong file

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have two files -
1) JSP file
2) HTML file

Whenever I run the project , the jsp one gets executed first. How can I run the HTML one first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the structure of your web.xml file with:

```
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>Name of the html file</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml` you can give the file which you need to show first.

By default it is the below one.

```
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
```

So give your html file name here.

```
<welcome-file>MyHtml.html</welcome-file>
```